# Postgresql Replication solutions and their performance

Tags: java, performance, postgresql, replication, high-availability

I am doing POC on Posgtresql replication. I am using latest version of postgresql i.e. 9.1. There are multiple replication solutions avaliable in the market (PGCluster, Pgpool-II, Slony-I). Postgresql also provide in-built replication solutions (Streaming replication, Warm Standby and hot standby). I am confused which solution is best for the financial application for which I am doing POC. The application will write around 160 million records with row size of 2.5 KB in database. My questions is for following scenarios which replication solution will be suitable:

- If I would require replication for backup purpose only
- If I would require to scale the reads
- If I would require High Avaliability and Consistency

Also It will be very helpful if you can share the perfomance or experience with postgresql replication solutions.

Comment: This belongs to dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: "The application will write around 160 million records" - daily? in total? monthly?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is "whatever your problem is, there is a solution."

Let's look at just a few of he main ones.

1. Slony-I is a replication solution that allows you to scale reads across part or all of your database.  This is designed so that you could take part of your database and replicate it into your DMZ for, say, customer reports.  On the other hand, this flexibility begets complexity, and while Slony lets you replicate only part of your database, Slony lets you replicate only part of your database......   Also Slony's flexibility doesn't stop there.  It allows you to replicate across different versions of Pgsql, therefore making sure you have zero downtime for read queries during major upgrades.
2. Postgres-XC is really the successor in spirit to PGCluster.  It offers Teradata-style clustering for PostgreSQL.  If you really need to scale reads and writes, this is the solution for you but again that adds complexity too.
3. The built-in replication solutions are simplest, allow you to scale for purposes of taking backups and taking writes.  It ensures high availability and consistency but a major upgrade requires downtime of all nodes.

So the thing is you need to figure out exactly what you want and then look for help in selecting the right tool for the job.  I would recommend asking on the pgsql-general email lists when you get to that point.